# How to slide a div open while sliding one closed that you clicked on?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Well I have been up for close to 48 hours now trying to get a site finished for a someone who needs up and running tomorrow afternoon. I bit off more than I can chew here for sure for what they asked for, and what I can do with the skills I got right now (man I got allot to learn).

Let's see if I can explain:

1. There are two banner images on screen, each have more content to expose.
2. If a user clicks the banner it should slide up to close. And the box below it slides down to open for more content.
3. If another banner is clicked it goes through the same process, but the one that was already open should slide shut and the original banner slides open putting it back to it's original state.

So far all I got is a click that pops open the box below the banner if it is clicked. And if another banner is clicked then it closes and that banners information is shown.

Allot to ask I guess but thought I would ask now while get going further cause lord knows I am gonna get stuck.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.pp-post-item').on('click', function() {
    let postFullId = jQuery(this).attr('id');
    let postNumId = postFullId.slice(13);
    $('.pp-post-container').not('.element-invisible').addClass('element-invisible');
    $('#pp-post-container-' + postNumId).removeClass('element-invisible');
  });
});
```

```css
.pp-post {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #3f3f3f;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.pp-post-item {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.pp-post-container {
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* initially hide divs on page load */

.element-invisible {
  position: absolute !important;
  height: 1px;
  width: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px);
  /* IE6, IE7 */
  clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pp-post-1" class="pp-post">
  <div id="pp-post-item-1" class="pp-post-item">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
<div id="pp-post-container-1" class="pp-post-container element-invisible">
  ...
</div>
<div id="pp-post-2" class="pp-post">
  <div id="pp-post-item-2" class="pp-post-item">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
<div id="pp-post-container-2" class="pp-post-container element-invisible">
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: How your banners are positioned ? both banners are horizontally aligned?

Comment: they are full width, lined up vertically. If I am adding and removing a class to these would all i need is css transitions? tyring that but not working for me.

Comment: Well I can get it to work sorta with transitions but I have to explicitly set a height. Problem is I don't know how big these will be with content in them.

Comment: You should set max-height instead of height. Set it to a value that won't be reached like 9999px.

Comment: Ok, it is sliding open gracefully. But I can't get it to slide closed gracefully it just dissapears. I tried checking for min-height in the transition but that doesn't work.

Comment: Any reason why you're rolling your own accordion? You could use this one: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/simple-jquery-accordion/, and then adapt it to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this kind of solution ? I create this base according to my understanding about your question.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('.bottom-layer').hide();
 
 
 $('#banner-one,#banner-two').click(function(){
      $(this).find('.top-layer').slideToggle("slow");
      $(this).find('.bottom-layer').slideToggle("slow");
 })
 
  


});
```

```css
#banner-container{
  max-width:600px;
  min-height:300px;
  overflow:hidden;
  background-color:#eee;
  display:inline-block;
}

#banner-one{
  min-width:600px;
  min-height:150px;
  background-color:orange;
  cursor:pointer;

 
}
#banner-two{
  min-width:600px;
  min-height:150px;
  background-color:red;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="banner-container">
  <div id=banner-one>
      <div class="top-layer">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Maecenas porttitor congue massa. Fusce posuere, magna sed pulvinar ultricies, purus lectus malesuada libero, sit amet commodo magna eros quis urna.</div>
      <div class="bottom-layer">Inside content</div>
  </div>

  <div id=banner-two>
  <div class="top-layer">Top Content</div>
      <div class="bottom-layer">Inside content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution opens the next div when the title is clicked, and closes all other divs.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.toggle').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('closed')) {
      $('h3').removeClass('open');
      $(this).removeClass('closed');
      $(this).addClass('open');
      $('.toggle-content').hide();
      $(this).next('.toggle-content').show();
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass('open');
      $(this).addClass('closed');
      $(this).next('.toggle-content').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
h3 {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #000;
}

.toggle-content {
  display: none;
  /* if you want content divs open by default, change to display: block*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h3 class="closed toggle">title 1</h3>
  <div class="toggle-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In et urna libero. Nullam scelerisque pellentesque porttitor. Ut aliquam malesuada enim, porttitor sodales nisl faucibus eu. Etiam non ex orci. Vestibulum augue mauris, pharetra cursus urna dapibus,
    ullamcorper fermentum nibh. Nullam tincidunt ante sed arcu mollis volutpat. Sed non fringilla eros. Nullam tortor diam, volutpat at ex aliquam, viverra posuere ante. Integer vehicula lacus nisl, in imperdiet lectus condimentum eu.
  </div>
  <h3 class="closed toggle">title 1</h3>
  <div class="toggle-content">
    Vestibulum suscipit laoreet est et faucibus. Pellentesque accumsan magna fermentum mauris sagittis, vel lobortis ante euismod. Nam luctus luctus neque non elementum. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Donec vel augue eu est volutpat tincidunt porttitor
    id justo. Sed sit amet quam dui. Fusce eget congue ipsum, nec finibus ex. Aliquam vestibulum eget diam at consequat. Morbi vitae neque auctor, posuere velit pharetra, sodales risus. Maecenas eget sodales odio. Etiam faucibus urna eu ligula fringilla
    interdum. Donec pulvinar, enim eget cursus dignissim, dui dolor facilisis felis, varius porta libero urna ac odio. In risus ligula, fringilla sit amet mattis dapibus, elementum eget sapien. Sed vulputate neque nec libero efficitur, a tincidunt nunc
    pulvinar. Donec vehicula malesuada turpis, vel pulvinar massa accumsan eu.
  </div>
</div>
```